# Bluetooth Low Energy: listening for notifications/indications on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

How is it possible to authenticate using Bluez 5.31 and GattTool?

I want to listen on a notification.

I've connected using `gatttool -b <addr> -I` and I can run the primary command etc.

I sniffed the device and I know that handle 0x0024 is where I will find a notification.

When I try `char-write-req 0x0024 0100` I get `Error: Characteristic write Request failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write`

So I try `sec-level medium` and then `sec-level high` but I still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the same operation but without the interactive option I. In other words, try listening for notifications as follows: gatttool -l high -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 --char-write-req --handle=0x24 --value=0100 --listen

Comment: Thanks Yousif. I tried that and the result was the same. I've sort of come the the conclusion that this particular devices is secured in a way that it requires me to write some values to a couple of other attributes in order to unlock it. Does that sound right/plausible? Unfortunately I'm currently unable to figure out exactly what those values should be and how to write them. I've sniffed the communication from an App that Works with the device and I can see that the attributes I'm suspecting I need to write to get's different values written to them each time the App connects.